# hadoop warn EBADF: Bad file descriptor

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce, warnings

I'm new in Hadoop and tried to write relation join using Hadoop. The algorithm tries to join three relations in two consecutive rounds. I used recursive method. The program is working fine. But during execution it tries to print a warning like this:

```
14/12/02 10:41:16 WARN io.ReadaheadPool: Failed readahead on ifile                                                                                                                  
EBADF: Bad file descriptor                                                                                                                                                          
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posix_fadvise(Native Method)                                                                                                
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:263)                                                                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX$CacheManipulator.posixFadviseIfPossible(NativeIO.java:142)                                                                  
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.ReadaheadPool$ReadaheadRequestImpl.run(ReadaheadPool.java:206)                                                                                      
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                                                                                          
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)                                                                                          
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is annoying and I want to know the cause of the problem and how to get rid of them. My code is as below:

```
public class Recursive {  
    /**
     * Join three relations together using recursive method
     * R JOIN S JOIN T = ((R JOIN S) JOIN T)
     */
    static String[] relationSequence;           // Keeps sequence of relations in join
    static int round;                           // Round number running
    /**
     * Mapper
     * Relation name = R
     * Input tuple   = a    b
     * Output pair   = (b, (R,a))
     * We assume that join value is the last attribute for the first relation
     * and the first attribute for the second relation.
     * So using this assumption, this map-reduce algorithm will work for any number of attributes  
     */
    public static class joinMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text>{
        public void map(Object keyIn, Text valueIn, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // Read tuple and put attributes in a string array
            String curValue = valueIn.toString();
            String[] values = curValue.split("\t");
            // Get relation name from input file name
            String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
            // Get join attribute index number R join S
            int joinIndex;
            String others = "";
            if(fileName.compareTo(relationSequence[round])==0){
                joinIndex = 0;
                others = curValue.substring(0+2);
            }else{
                joinIndex = values.length - 1;
                others = curValue.substring(0, curValue.length()-2);
            }
            IntWritable joinValue = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(values[joinIndex]));

            // Create list of attributes which are not join attribute
            Text temp = new Text(fileName + "|" + others);
            context.write(joinValue,temp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reducer
     * 
     *  1. Divide the input list in two ArrayLists based on relation name:
     *      a. first relation
     *      b. second relation
     *  2. Test if the second relation is not empty. If it's so, we shouldn't continue.
     *  3. For each element of the first array list, join it with the all elements in
     *     the second array list
     */
    public static class joinReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
        public void reduce(IntWritable keyIn, Iterable<Text> valueIn, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            ArrayList<String> firstRelation = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> secondRelation = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Text value : valueIn) {
                String[] values = value.toString().split("\\|");
                if(values[0].compareTo(relationSequence[round])==0){
                    secondRelation.add(values[1]);
                }else{
                    firstRelation.add(values[1]);
                }
            }
            if(secondRelation.size()>0){
                for (String firstItem : firstRelation) {
                    for (String secondItem : secondRelation) {
                        context.write(new Text(firstItem.toString()), new Text(keyIn.toString() + "\t"
                                                                            + secondItem.toString() 
                                                                            ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Partitioner
     * 
     * In order to hash pairs to reducer tasks, we used logical which is 
     * obviously faster than module function.
     */
    public static class joinPartitioner extends Partitioner<IntWritable, Text> {
        public int getPartition(IntWritable key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
                int partitionNumber = key.get()&0x007F;
                return partitionNumber;
            }
     }

     /**
      * Main method
      * 
      * (R join S join T)
      * hadoop jar ~/COMP6521.jar Recursive /input/R /input/S /input2/T /output R,S,T
      * 
      * @param args
      * <br> args[0]: first relation
      * <br> args[1]: second relation
      * <br> args[2]: third relation
      * <br> args[3]: output directory
      * <br> args[4]: relation sequence to join, separated by comma
      */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        /****** Preparing problem variables *******/
        relationSequence = args[4].split(",");      // Keep sequence of relations
        round = 1;                                  // Variable to keep current round number
        int maxOfReducers = 128;                    // Maximum number of available reducers
        int noReducers;                             // Number of reducers for one particular job
        noReducers = maxOfReducers;

        Path firstRelation  = new Path(args[0]);
        Path secondRelation = new Path(args[1]);
        Path thirdRelation  = new Path(args[2]);
        Path temp           = new Path("/temp");    // Temporary path to keep intermediate result
        Path out            = new Path(args[3]);
        /****** End of variable Preparing   *******/

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        /****** Configuring first job *******/
//      General configuration
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Recursive multi-way join (first round)");
        job.setNumReduceTasks(noReducers);

//      Pass appropriate classes
        job.setJarByClass(Recursive.class);
        job.setMapperClass(joinMapper.class);
        job.setPartitionerClass(joinPartitioner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(joinReducer.class);

//      Specify input and output type of reducers
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(temp)){ fs.delete(temp, true);}
        if(fs.exists(out)) { fs.delete(out, true); }

//      Specify the input and output paths  
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, firstRelation);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, secondRelation);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, temp);
        /****** End of first job configuration *******/
        job.submit();
//      Running the first job
        boolean b = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        if(b){
//          try to execute the second job after completion of the first one
            round++;                    // Specify round number
            Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();  // Create new configuration object

            /****** Configuring second job *******/
//          General configuration
            Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "Reduce multi-way join (second round)");
            job2.setNumReduceTasks(noReducers);

//          Pass appropriate classes
            job2.setJarByClass(Recursive.class);
            job2.setMapperClass(joinMapper.class);
            job2.setPartitionerClass(joinPartitioner.class);
            job2.setReducerClass(joinReducer.class);

//          Specify input and output type of reducers
            job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

//          Specify input and output type of mappers
            job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
            job2.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
//          End of 2014-11-25
//          Specify the input and output paths  
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, temp);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, thirdRelation);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, out);
            /****** End of second job configuration *******/
            job2.submit();
//          Running the first job
            b = job2.waitForCompletion(true);

//          Output time measurement
            long e = System.currentTimeMillis() - s;
            System.out.println("Total: " + e);
            System.exit(b ? 0 : 1);
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar error and I end up on your question, and this [mail list thread EBADF: Bad file descriptor](http://marc.info/?l=hadoop-user&m=137348237227681&w=2)

> To clarify a little bit, the readahead pool can sometimes spit out this
>   message if you close a file while a readahead request is in flight.  It's
>   not an error and just reflects the fact that the file was closed hastily,
>   probably because of some other bug which is the real problem.

In my case I was closing a writer without flushing it with `hflush`

Since you don't seem to use by hand a writer or a reader, I would probably have a look to how you are sending the mr task.